# Unable to catch shutdown signals with PM2 and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, process, pm2

Goodmorning,

I'm experiencing a lot of difficulties of capturing the shutdown signals inside a server that is run with PM2.
I've already read a lot of articles and tried a lot of answers but nothing seems to be working.

My setup:
PM2 v2.10.0 (Due to some problems running the newest PM2 (3.2.2 and 3.2.3) related to a continuesly popping CMD screen),
NodeJS v6.11.3 (As this is the version supported by our application),
Windows 10.0.17134 Build 17134

I have tried the following solutions:

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.info("Received the SIGINT signal to shut down.");
})

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.info('Received the SIGTERM signal to shut down');
})

process.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.info('Message received');
    if (msg == 'shutdown') {
        console.info('Shutdown message received');
    }
})

process.on('exit', () => {
    console.info('Received exit signal');
})
```

Of which I later read that this will only work on Linux and not on Windows. On Windows the proposed solution is :

```
var rl = require("readline").createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.on("SIGINT", function () {
    console.info('Inside readline SIGNINT')
    process.emit("SIGINT");
});

rl.on('SIGTERM', function () {
    console.info('Inside readline SIGTERM')
    process.emit('SIGTERM')
});

rl.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.info('Inside readline message')
    process.emit(msg);
})
```

But unfortunately this did not work either. I'm actually at a loss as to how to solve this.
When I run the server.js using the command line command *node server.js* I can see that it does catch the signals correctly with the above code.

Does somebody have any idea what could be happening here ? I've also tried upgrading the PM2 version to the latest (3.2.3) but to no avail either.

**UPDATE**

What I see in the *pm2.log* is a repeatedly printed line:

```
2018-12-13T11:07:43: PM2 log: App [PROXY:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
```

This would indicate that my NodeJS server is not properly shutting down, but I also cannot seem to get the fault in that, as it works when running it from the CMD.

Comment: hey, I cannot see window popping with latest Node 10.x and latest PM2 (3.2.3), are you using any module like pm2-server-monit?

Comment: We have to use NodeJS v6.11.3 and cannot (yet) upgrade to the latest stable LTS version of NodeJS. Thus I cannot confirm or deny your question.
I've updated the question with additional information though.

Comment: Can you have a look to this project: https://github.com/feifeipan/childprocess-exit?
Else it seems impossible right now for a child process to detect the SIGINT signal sent from a parent. I might find an idea